# Setup differences php 5.2 and 5.3

Tags: php, installation

I have a php that generates a XML file. It begins with the following code:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FileName.xml"');

// Outputs a lot of XML
```

When I'm running PHP 5.2 it works fine, but on 5.3 an empty file is generated. Any ideas about why it's empty?

Comment: Post the complete code, I doubt if headers have anything special to do in this scenario.

Comment: did you try this on same sever setup?  I would say it is probably not caused by difference in php version, rather something else. for instance try this and see if it works.  ob_start(); at the very beginning before header. and at the very end of the file; $xml=ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); echo $xml;

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like it could be related to short open tags functionality: `<?` vs `<?php`?

make sure you have short open tags disabled in your `php.ini`. if you need it activated, there's a workaround: for `<?xml` tag, wrap it in a string and echo it, so it will not be interpreted as the start of a php block by php

```
echo '<?xml … >';
```